# DataGridView corrupting data after scroll?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am new to Win Forms, however I am experiencing a very weird issue with a DataGridView.

I am binding this DataGridView with JSON Data using Newtonsoft.

Everything is working perfectly, except that when there's lots of rows and you scroll through those rows, when you return to Row 1 it is completely corrupted.

I'll post some pics for reference:

Just loaded the table everything is good:

[image: Here everything is good]

Scrolled to the bottom of the table, still good

[image]

But now when I return to the top, Row 1 is messed:

[image]

Does anyone know what this issue could be? I am sorry if it's something silly. I'm new to Win Forms.

Comment: Without proper observation of code it's tough to anwer. But Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481081/scrolling-in-datagridview-causes-overwritten-text

Comment: Did you add code to some event handlers of your DGV? Are you looping Rows, for some reason? Other?

Comment: @Jimi Not doing anything of the sort, but through further testing I've found out it has to do with the selection. When the selection goes to row 1 after scrolling it messes "the data" up. Probably like the other answer suggests, related to the colors, I will try the proposed solution later today.

Comment: Glad you were able to make your code work. The double buffering of DataGridView can also solve the problem of flickering when displaying data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone's interested, after trying out Pete's solution before, a black background appeared over the selected row.

After making it DoubleBuffered, I had to add the following to the CellFormating method. Now it works fine :)

```
private void myDGV_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) {
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
        e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a strange issue - although it almost looks like a graphics drawing problem with the way that in the 3rd screenshot you see two rows on top of each other. That's just a guess.

You could try setting double buffering for the dataGridView to true as follows.

This would be a method in your form.cs file for the form that your DataGridView is on:

```
private void setDoubleBuffer(Control myDGV, bool doubleBuffered)
{
    typeof(Control).InvokeMember("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, myDGV, new object[] { doubleBuffered });
}
```

Then add this in the form constructor:

```
public myForm()
{
    setDoubleBuffer(myDGV, true);
}
```

See if that does anything for you.